# Azure Cosmos DB Trigger event timestamp

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I use Azure Function Cosmos DB Trigger which is very simple. It just pushes the same message into Storage Queue. Later from this storage queue, the messages are processed. I'm trying to get a time when the Cosmos DB trigger was fired in Cosmos DB. I need an increasing timestamp (ideally time) which I can later use in Storage Queue processing function to distinguish which Cosmos DB trigger was first.

My AZ Cosmos DB trigger looks like this

```
[FunctionName("CosmosTrigger")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "DbTesting",
            containerName: "test",
            Connection  = "CosmosDBConnection",
            LeaseContainerName  = "test_leases",
            CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists  = true,
            FeedPollDelay = 1000)]
            IReadOnlyList<DbModel> modifiedModels,
            ILogger log) 
{
 ** Push model message to Storage Queue for later processing **
}
```

The idea behind this is that when the processing of a message fails it is pushed back to Storage Queue for retry.

Is there any attribute/object that I can add to the function declaration from which I can get the event time stamp?

I do not want to use this approach

```
{
  var etag = DateTime.Now;
  ** Push model message with **etag** to Storage Queue for later processing **
}
```

because what if the processing of the first AZ is delayed or takes longer to that etag point than for the second? Then the second AZ will have lower time?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the date time value in Cosmos DB and get it in Azure CosmosDb Function. As blew code show.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace _72966054_3
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "Studenttable",
            collectionName: "students",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "ConnectionStrings:cosmosdb",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases", CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists =true)]IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
            ILogger log)
        {
            if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
            {
                dynamic list = JObject.Parse(input[0].ToString());
                string t = Convert.ToString(list.Date +" "+ list.Time);
                log.LogInformation("CosmQuery Time " + t); // This time come from Azure Cosmos Db.
                log.LogInformation("Timestamp Time " + input[0].Timestamp);
                log.LogInformation("Function  Time " + System.DateTime.UtcNow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :-**
[image]

**Azure Cosmos Db data:-**
[image]

> Is there any attribute/object that I can add to the function
> declaration from which I can get the event time stamp?

You can store this time and process your requirement, if the process failed, then you have cosmos event time.